# convert all the characters in html special characters

Tags: php

is there any way to convert all the characters in html special characters html using php?

I did some research and I found this function: "htmlspecialchars". But I did not understand how to use it.

someone can give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Its well explained.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for ALL the html characters use htmlentities(). This function is identical to htmlspecialchars() in all ways, except with htmlentities(), all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are translated into these entities.

```
<?php
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";

// Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str);

// Outputs: A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
```

Citatation: Lifted directly from the php manual. [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Answer (score 0):

### htmlspecialchars

Usage of *`htmlspecialchars`*

```
$test = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
```

See for more informations: [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

---

there is another function called `htmlentities` which is identical to htmlspecialchars.

### htmlentities

Usage of *`htmlentities`*

```
$test = htmlentities("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
```

See for more informations: [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/htmlentities)

> The difference is what gets encoded. The choices are everything
> (entities) or "special" characters, like ampersand, double and single
> quotes, less than, and greater than (specialchars).

**I recommend to use htmlspecialchars.**